# Hive TRANSFORM receives NULL for concatenated array values

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hiveql, user-defined-functions, hive-udf

I have a hive table in the format :

```
   col1.      col2.     col3.
    a1          b1       c1
    a1          b1       c2                                  
    a1          b2       c2
    a1          b2       c3              
    a2          b3       c1
    a2          b4       c1                                  
    a2          b4       c2
    a2          b4       c3              
    .
    .
```

Every value in **col1** can have multiple values in **col2** and every such pair of **(col1, col2)** can have multiple values of **col3**.

I am running the query **[Q]**:

```
select col1, col2, collect_list(col3) from {table} group by col1, col2;
```

to get:

```
a1   b1   [c1, c2]
a1   b2   [c2, c3]
a2   b3   [c1]
a2   b4   [c1, c2, c3]
```

I want to do some transformations using a python UDF. So Im passing all these columns to UDF using TRANSFORM clause as:

```
select TRANSFORM ( * ) using 'python udf.py' FROM 
(
select col1, col2, concat_ws('\t', collect_list(col3)) from {table} group by col1, col2;
)
```

I'm using concat_ws to convert the array output to strig from collect_list concatenated by separator. I get col1, col2 in result, but do not get the col3 output.

```
+---------+---------+
|      key|    value|
+---------+---------+
|a1       | b1      |
|         |     null|
|a1       | b2      |
|         |     null|
|a2       | b3      |
|         |     null|
|a2       | b4      |
|         |     null|
+---------+---------+
```

In my UDF, I just have a print statement that prints the line received from stdin.

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    try:
        print line
    except Exception as e:
        continue
```

can someone help figure out why i'm not getting the col3 in my UDF ?

Comment: Can you post the code of your UDF? it's hard to say what's wrong without the code. Plus `\t` in `concat_ws` is not the best separator as tab is used to separate columns. As alternative you may use comma or semicolon.

Comment: @serge_k I have added the UDF code. Also, I have already tried comma, semicolon etc with `concat_ws`. Still getting the same result. Is there any other alternative function to use in place of `concat_ws` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to parse the line in Python UDF, e.g.,

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    try:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        col1, col2, col3 = line.split('\t')
        print '\t'.join([col1, col2, col3])
    except Exception as e:
        continue
```

Then it's better to use something else instead of `\t` in concat_ws

```
select TRANSFORM ( * )  using 'python udf.py' as (col1, col2, col3)
FROM 
(
select col1, col2, concat_ws(',', collect_list(col3)) from {table} group by col1, col2;
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I had tried split('\t') before, not sure what was problem then.

Comment: Anyway, in my UDF, I'm trying to aggregate all info for each unique col1 in a dict and dump to json. something like:
`d = { "col1": "a1", "col2": [ "b1", "b2"], col3: ["c1", "c2", "c3"]}`
So in my UDF, I do a `print json.dumps(d)` after i've created the JSON by agg. of rows. But I end up getting:
`{"col1": "a1", "col2" : "b1", "col3": ["c1", "c2"] }`,  
`{"col1": "a1", "col2" : "b2", "col3": ["c2", "c3"] }`
`{"col1": "a2", "col2" : "b3", "col3": ["c1"] } ... `
I would expect `group by` to send rows in UDF grouped by the given columns, so the agg on col1 would work. Not sure whats wrong.